# Not able to export GridView data to Excel on production server

Tags: asp.net

On my web page I have an Export button to export GridView data to MS Excel.

In the Solution Explorer, I have a folder named Excel Templates which contains few template with charts.

When Export button is clicked on the web page, a copy of this template is created in another folder and GridView data gets written into it.

When I run my local solution, the Export works fine, but when I deploy my application to production server after publishing it, the Export functionality hangs in between.

It is neither showing any error nor opening the Excel sheet.

Is there any specific strategy to deploy these external files?

Comment: Can you post your export function?

Comment: Can you verify that ASP.NET account (e.g. Network Services on Windows 2008+) has correct permissions? Read for the first directory, Read/Write for the second?

Comment: @tymeJV I don't have it now. But we have two servers, Test Server and Production. It is working well when deployed to Test Server but not working on Production server.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter I need to check this.

Comment: Are you using `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`?

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ Yes I am using Interop.